# After Upgrading EE5->EE6: Warning with plugin

Tags: upgrade

after having upgraded from EE5.4.2 to EE6.0.6 I get a warning in the frontend:

> Warning Class "ExpressionEngine\Addons\ReadingTime\Reading_time" not
> found ee/ExpressionEngine/Core/Autoloader.php, line 91
>
> Severity: E_WARNING

The concerned plugin is a real small and easy plugin with only some lines of code (the [Reading Time from EllisLab](https://github.com/EllisLab/Reading-Time).
I don't understand the error - does it tell me that the plugin is old/deprecated somehow or is there any other problem?

Any hint would help me further, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the ReadingTime addon from the [EllisLab Github](https://github.com/EllisLab/Reading-Time).
I think it disappeared from the pre-installed addons for EE6 as part of the change over from EllisLab ownership to opensource.

I can confirm that it works fine in EE6 - you just need to add it like any other third-party add-on.

HTH

Comment: The problem was that the namespace has changed (though the pi-file is exactly the same). Uninstalled and uploaded the most recent addon.setup.php, installed via CP and it worked. Thanks for your mentioning that it works for you with EE6, this motivated me to investigate further -> +1 :-)